# Map all requests from a subdomain to a different url

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a server that responds to www.server.com/api

and I would like to have that same server respond to api.server.com

currently, I set up api.server.com to be an alias of www.server.com in my vhosts file, but I need to write a rule to add the /api on all requests with the api.server.com domain.

I've tried this:

```
RewriteEngine  on
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} api.server.com
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /api/$1 [L,R=301]
```

but either way I play around with this, I get 500 because of a loop condition.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description you do *not* want to implement an external redirection. Instead try that:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^api\.server\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /api/$1 [L]
```

It will have all requests to `https://api.server.com/...` get processed by `/api/...` *without* rewriting the visible URL in the browser. Also it will *not* result in an endless rewriting loop for direct or internal requests to `/api/...`.

If you operate a current version of the apache http server you can replace the old `L` flag with the `END` flag which will prevent an additional rewriting iteration, thus save time and performance.

Comment: That's exactly what I want, but it's still not working after adding the second condition and I'm getting 500 because of internal redirections.

Comment: Sure you are not looking at a cached result?

Comment: no, it's something else in the vhost file that's making it behave badly, I'll post it.

Comment: Ok, sounds interesting. If you have issues finding out _exactly_ what intervenes, then rewrite logging might shed additional light at what exactly is going on inside your rewriting module.